# UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. - When using Internet Explorer

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

1. I tried to run the below testcase using IE Driver got failed every time but the same code was successful when run using chrome driver as well as edge driver.
2. OS version: Windows 10
3. My selenium version: 4.1.2
4. Browser version: Internet Explorer 11
5. IE Driver version: 4.0.0
6. Tried using 32bit IE Driver as well as 64bit IE Driver but still facing the same issue.
7. I have mentioned the code which produced the error

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
   public class amazon 
   {
       public void ama() throws InterruptedException
           {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\HP\\eclipse-workspace\\Sample project\\Driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
                String pagetitle=driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println("The title of the webpage is : " + pagetitle);
                if(pagetitle.equals("Online Shopping site in India: Shop Online for Mobiles, Books, Watches, Shoes and More - Amazon.in"))
                    System.out.println("Pass");
                else
                    System.out.println("Fail");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.quit();
           }
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
           {
                amazon o= new amazon();
                o.ama();
           }
   }
   ```
8. The code runs and triggers the internet explorer to open, then the browser opens and directs to the specified url but then it doesn't close the browser and failed to return the page title as well as the boolean value and the code never reaches to the `driver.quit();` code line.
9. But instead the code just runs internally for about 3-5 minutes and returns the below exceptions and error in the console.
10. I got the exceptions in the **console** which i have mentioned completely below

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
4.0.0.0
Listening on port 61125
Only local connections are allowed
Mar 08, 2022 3:35:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-NL2V6IHF', ip: '192.168.43.71', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.14'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Command: [e76495ba-7511-46a7-94fb-feb46fb752bd, get {url=https://www.amazon.in/}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.edgechromium: false, ie.edgepath: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:61125/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: e76495ba-7511-46a7-94fb-feb46fb752bd
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:327)
    at Selenium.amazon.ama(amazon.java:33)
    at Selenium.amazon.main(amazon.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61125
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$6(RetryRequest.java:80)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:48)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Execution.executeSync(Execution.java:128)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:379)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get(FailsafeExecutor.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$7(RetryRequest.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$6(RetryRequest.java:80)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:48)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$supply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:66)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.Execution.executeSync(Execution.java:128)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:379)
    at net.jodah.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get(FailsafeExecutor.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.RetryRequest.lambda$apply$7(RetryRequest.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61125
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:179)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:108)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:61125
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:710)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: The code is right. I test the code and it works. Have you met the [Required Configuration](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ie_driver_server/#required-configuration) before automating IE? Please check and make sure you have met all the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the driver to a newest version or to a version that matches your IE browser.
2. The path to the driver is wrong, change it.
3. You are using a `static` class wrong. Make all the method static and call them from the main:

   ```
   public static void ama() throws InterruptedException
        {    
            // Method code goes here
            // call driver.quit() outside of the if-else block                 
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
        {            
            ama();
        }
   ```

Comment: Nope i had the updated driver and if the path to driver was incorrect then how come my internet explorer will run?